# Difference between a row of a column with the next row of a different column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this -

```
Img  x1 y1  x2   y4  Height Text
7   165 87  236  101    14  Shinner s
8   240 87  274  101    14  cary
9   290 87  317  101    14  Tate
10  324 87  389  104    17  Adress)
11  608 87  673  101    14  SHipper
12  690 87  815  101    14  ACC OLN MLITTHS
13  903 87  933  101    14  Not
14  937 87  1018 101    14  necotiapla
35  906 162 953  175    13  issven
36  960 162 984  179    17  OY
```

I'd like to compute to distance between 'x2' of a row and 'x1' of the subsequent row, and for if the difference between them is less than 75, group the values in 'Text' together to form a new dataframe

Eg -

Expected output -

```
Index Text
1     Shinners cary Tate Adress)
2     SHipper ACC OLN MLITTHS
3     Not necotiapla
4     issven OY
```

Comment: why shipper did not belong to 1st group ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can do:

```
mask = df['x2'].shift().sub(df['x1']).abs()
df.Text.groupby(mask.gt(75).cumsum()).apply(' '.join)
```

Output:

```
0    Shinners cary Tate Adress)
1       SHipper ACC OLN MLITTHS
2                Not necotiapla
3                     issven OY
Name: Text, dtype: object
```

---

If you want the `Img` column, you can do:

```
df.groupby(mask.gt(75).cumsum()).agg({'Img':list, 'Text':' '.join})
```

Output:

```
             Img                        Text
0  [7, 8, 9, 10]  Shinners cary Tate Adress)
1       [11, 12]     SHipper ACC OLN MLITTHS
2       [13, 14]              Not necotiapla
3       [35, 36]                   issven OY
```

Comment: This works! Thank you. Is there a way to add the index of the rows that have been grouped together?